# Emoticons not working in HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to use emoticons like this one  on a HTML form, that will store them on a MySQL DB and then will be displayed on a PHP page, but when I paste it, it just give me a blank space. I've used the `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` tag. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported here. (Check your post, it showed up as a box) Do you know its HTML entity code #?

Comment: Really? That's weird, I'm seeing it as a smiley face on Firefox. Yes, it's U+1F604 SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES

Comment: Smiley on OSX Safari as well, but not on chrome.

Comment: Show the relevant HTML and CSS code. If PHP or MySQL are relevant, explain how. If using forms is relevant, explain how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entity is only support on a few font faces, check [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%F0%9F%98%84+-+Unicode+Character+%27SMILING+FACE+WITH+OPEN+MOUTH+AND+SMILING+EYES%27+%28U%2B1F604%29).

If I change the font to Segoe UI Symbol, it shows up fine, whereas using Arial doesn't work.

```html
<font face="Segoe UI Symbol">&#x1f604;</font><br><br>
<font face="Arial">&#x1f604;</font>
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the font being used for the input.

Comment: In conforming browsers, the character is displayed if any of the fonts in the system contains it. And setting the font does not help unless the user’s system has that font. Segoe UI Symbol exists in some new versions of Windows only.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela This doesn't seem to be the case for me though. I'm running Chrome 38 and even though I do have fonts that support this character, the original post is not showing this character at all. Here's a [screenshot](http://puu.sh/cRRLK/9ceb9847f3.png) of what I'm seeing.

Comment: Yes, the other thing needed is to set the characters to utf8mb4, both in the html page and in the db field collation and then you're ready to go.